# Remover caracteres de uma string entre dois caracteres específicos em java

Tags: java, string

Tenho uma `String` que contém o caminho de arquivo, e preciso remover os caracteres que vem após a última `"/"` até o fim da string. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso? ...

Exemplo:

```
String comando = "C:/Users/Vinicius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ProjetoORI/retiramarca.exe"
```

Quero apagar o `"retiramarca.exe"`

```
 caminho = pesquisaInfo.getText();
    chave = recebeConfirme.getText();

    caminhoInvertido = caminho.replace("\\", "/");

if (actionCommand.equals("Encrypt File")) {

    String comando = "C:/Users/Vinicius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ProjetoORI/inseremarca.exe " + chave + " " + caminhoInvertido;
    try {
        System.out.println(caminhoInvertido.getParentFile());
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start " + comando);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    System.out.println(actionCommand);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arquivo criptografado");
```

Comment: Não precisa de regex pra isso. Adiciona o código ai que você está utilizando, tem soluções sem regex pra recuperar isso.

Comment: Não só não precisa de regex como nem seria o mais apropriado, pois o que pretende é ir para a pasta anterior. Deverá fazer como o @Articuno indicou

Comment: Toda vida que você captura uma exceção e não a trata adequadamente, uma fada morre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando a classe [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html), é possível recuperar essa informação sem regex, através do método `getParent()`. Ele retorna o a pasta imediatamente superior ao caminho atual do arquivo.

```
String caminho = "C:/Users/Vinicius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ProjetoORI/inseremarca.exe";

System.out.println(new File(caminho).getParent());
```

Saida:

> C:\Users\Vinicius\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjetoORI

Veja funciona no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/yp0U52)

O método `getParent()` retorna uma string com o caminho a um nível acima do local do arquivo.

Comment: Não estou utilizando a classe File. Na verdade, a string está recebendo o caminho através de um getText de um Jtextfield, o qual por sua vez recebeu o caminho pelo JFileChooser. Preciso passar essa variável por argumento com o Runtime.getRuntime, para que meu script em C recebe esse caminho e vá até o destino para buscar o arquivo e criptografá-lo. Vou mostrar o trecho do código...

Comment: @M.Vinicius e porque não converter em file, resgatar o caminho e fazer o cast pra string? Isso é menos custoso do que fazer regex,

Comment: Não havia pensado dessa maneira, é uma boa. Estou começando a programar em java agora..rs

Comment: @M.Vinicius Veja a edição.

Comment: Testei aqui, é isso mesmo que preciso. Obrigado! ... Só tem uma coisa, consigo colocar esse valo em uma String, pois preciso tratar a questão das barras, deixá-las invertidas.

Comment: @M.Vinicius perdão, mas fiz uma alteração significativa na resposta, o método getparent() faz a mesma coisa, só que ele não precisa de converter em string, o retorno já é desse tipo.

Comment: tudo bem, consegui fazer o tratamento que precisava. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @M.Vinicius não sei se já fez isso, mas uma dica de otimização é pegar o a variável `caminho` com o "nomedoarquivo.extensao" do seu campo de texto, fazer o código da resposta e trocar as barras em seguida. Assim você não terá que fazer a troca 2 vezes.

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso... está funcionando perfeitamente!

Answer (score 2):

Utilize as classes do pacote [`java.nio.*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) para tratar e manipular caminhos de arquivos e diretórios

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/Vinicius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ProjetoORI/inseremarca.exe")
                 .getParent();

// C:\Users\Vinicius\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjetoORI
System.out.println(path);
```